# On updating to Asp.Net Framework 4.5 > LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

The following code worked until I moved to Asp.net Framework 4.5.

```
        var dateAndPort = (from c in context.CruiseCalendar
                        where c.ShipId == sourceId
                        && c.CruiseDayDate >= dateRange.Start
                        && c.CruiseDayDate <= dateRange.End
                        select new DateAndPort
                        {
                            Date = c.CruiseDayDate,
                            DestinationId = c.ListingId
                        });

        var shipRendezvous = (from r in context.CruiseCalendar
                             where (dateAndPort.Any(d => d.Date == r.CruiseDayDate
                             && d.DestinationId == r.ListingId))
                             select r).GroupBy(x => x.CruiseDayDate) //Groups by date
                            .Where(x => x.Count() >= shipCount) // if shipCount for dateAndPort > 0 only rendezvous will be returned
                            .SelectMany(x => x)
                            .OrderBy(r => r.CruiseDayDate)
                            .ToList();

          return shipRendezvous;
```

Now this throws an error when executing the second query (var shipRendezvous = ). The error is in full:

> Unable to cast the type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[[Seven.Domain.CustomTypes.DateAndPort,
>   Seven.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'
>   to type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[Seven.Domain.CustomTypes.DateAndPort,
>   Seven.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM
>   primitive or enumeration types.

Any ideas whats going on?

(I affixed the first query with a .ToList() and now get this error: 
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Seven.Domain.CustomTypes.DateAndPort'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.)